# Modifying a word in its structure (spelling) to convey a different meaning?

Tags: morphology

Somewhere on the Internet I read the following lines:

> Daughter is not equal to tensions. Daughter is equal to ten-sons.

In this sentence the word "tension" is modified to be written as "ten-sons" to produce a positive connotation.

Is there any name to this form of writing, where a word is modified in its spelling/pronunciation to convey a different meaning?

Is it related to "semantic change"?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply call this a pun or a play on words, since the intent is likely humorous.

Interestingly, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun) also offers the synonymous term "paronomasia," if you'd like to impress your friends with a new word.

Comment: Yes, like "Pie are not square, pie are round. Cake are square."

Comment: @W9WBH Oof... Apparently you can cause pain with paronomasia.